# Extended bottom border at the right

Tags: html, css

How can I inextend the "MAKE YOU BURP" bottom border on the middle? In the right side of the food on plate, I tried to use margin: px; and it did work, but it affects other elements and the responsiveness of the webpage, is there any other way to do this without using margin: px;.

### SCREENSHOT

[image]

```css
#Main {
    background-image: url('pexels-fwstudio-164005.jpg');
    background-size: 1000px 700px;
}

#Main img {
    width: 440px;
}

#Main #main-content {
    display: inline-block;
}

#h2-last {
    border-width: thick;
    border-bottom: solid;
    /*margin-right: 1097px;*/
}

.main-content li, a {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.main-content ul {
    position: relative;
    right: 49px;
}

#main-text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 500px;
}

.main-content button {
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #F2A65A;
    padding: 20px 25px 20px 25px;
}
```

```html
            <div id="children-main">

                <div class="main-content">
                    <img src="Fish-Food-Plate-PNG.png" alt="fish in plate">
                    <div id="main-text">
                        <h2>BULALOI FOODS</h2>
                        <h2 id="h2-last">MAKE PEAOPLE BURP</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button><a href="">ORDER</a></button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button><a href="">MENU</a></button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: your code doesn't show the issue, fix your code and put it in a snippet. 
to solve this issue, you need to set a proper `width` for the element or use `text line` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the element width is set to fit content

```css
#h2-last {
    border-width: thick;
    border-bottom: solid;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="h2-last">MAKE PEAOPLE BURP</h2>
```